# How to remove scrollIntoView in componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, scroll, ref, unmount

I used refs to manage the `scroll` event

```
 <section ref={(tasks) => {
                this.tasks = tasks
              }}>
```

I am using `scrollIntoView` to scroll to a particular `div` on a `goToTasks` click.

```
 goToTasks = () => {
    this.tasks.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  })
  }
```

I want to remove the `scrollIntoView`. When I move to the next page. I get the same scroll Position in the new page.

How can I remove the remove `scrollIntoView` in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Can you you shows how did you assign to `refs`? Also are you going to the next page using react router?

Comment: <section ref={(tasks) => {
                this.tasks = tasks
              }}>

Comment: Are you looking for [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)?

Comment: @xehpuk No I am not

Comment: which version of react-router do you use

Comment: Then it's unclear what you're asking. You can change the scroll position with `window.scrollTo`.